# Is Dialog.show() a non-blocking method?

Tags: java, android

I've got a button that kicks off a background thread to do some work and I am trying to use a ProgressDialog to prevent the user from double clicking that button (or any other ui elements) while that work is being done.  The first thing I do in my buttons onClick code is to display the progress dialog, which takes over the screen.  The problem I am seeing is that if I rapidly tap this button, sometimes two or more presses will register before the ProgressDialog is shown.  This leads me to assume that ProgressDialog.show() is returning before the ProgressDialog is actually visible.

Can anybody confirm this?  Also, is there a way to change this behavior, or at least get a notification of when the dialog is actually visible?  I saw Dialog.onStart() but given the javadoc, this appears to be called before the Dialog is actually visible...

UPDATE:
While it appears that there is no good way of solving this problem in general, the following works for my situation where my work is done by an external thread and the amount of work to do takes longer than the time it takes for all the button clicks to be processed:

```
void myOnClickHandler() {
  if(myButton.isEnabled()) {
    myButton.setEnabled(False);
    // do work here
    // setEnabled(true) is invoked at the end of my spawned thread's run().
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't `setClickable(false)` on your Button, just inside the onClick and after you finished your Progress `setClickable(true)` again?

Comment: I'm trying to save that as a last resort.  The use of the progress dialog as a blocking mechanism is actually built into the work being done and I'd like to be able to reuse that mechanism if possible.

Comment: @RafaelT & Jave - While it sounds great, this actually does not prevent you from clicking a button more than once. If you click rapidly enough you will send off multiple clicks before the actual even handler is called that disables the button. So, it does work for most cases since most users aren't going to try and click buttons like crazy.. however, you will always have that one guy ....

Comment: I'm thinking a possible workaround might be to setEnabled(false) combined with wrapping the button's work in an if (button.isEnabled() {...}.

Comment: @Nick - A solution would just be to have a task/thread object as a member variable. If that object is null when you enter your onClick handler - Use a synchronized block to initialize that thread/async task and start it..   If it is not null when you enter the onClick it means you've already started running your thread and you should just return from your click handler without doing anything.

Comment: @dymmeh is that synch really necessary?  isnt it always the same thread (ie the main thread) processing button events? if so, i would think that just manually checking whether enabled is true/false would be 100% equivalent.

Comment: @Nick - you should be able to do that, yes. I just proposed how i'd do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The problem is you clicked many times before the click event is delivered. (i.e. it is queued before you run `ProgressDialog.show()`.)

Comment: To me this implies that setEnabled(false) will not work either?  Is there any way to guard against this situation without writing some kind of filter in the button handler code that checks click timestamps?

Comment: accepted as the answer since this was the first response to characterize the underlying issue.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've noticed in Android you can double click on a button rapidly and have the onClick listener fire twice (or even more) regardless of the code in the listener (even if you disable the button immediately).

I reported a bug a while ago here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20073 but of course these things tend to go "unnoticed" by Google. Feel free to star it in hopes of getting Google's attention